# Convert a Llinq query from All matches to OR (at least one tag needs to match)

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

This query returns door IDs  which the the door_id has all its tags matching.

```
List<decimal> matchingDoors  db.tags
    .Where(x => x.user_id == userId && (null == SystemId|| x.syid == SystemId)) 
    .GroupBy(x => x.door_id)        
    .Where(x => tags.All(y =>
           x.Any(z => z.name == y)))
    .Select(x => x.Key).ToList<decimal>();
```

How can I change the query to return results that match at least one tag ('OR')?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name check this out.

Comment: It returns only those who match both.

Comment: Wrong query, updating the question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've update the question

Comment: does not that work if you just replace "All" with "Any"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Contains()` method on `tags` collection. Here you are:

```
List<decimal> matchingDoors  db.tags
    .Where(x => x.user_id == userId && (null == SystemId|| x.syid == SystemId)) 
    .GroupBy(x => x.door_id)        
    .Where(x => x.Any(y => tags.Contains(y))) //this is where magic
    .Select(x => x.Key).ToList<decimal>();
```